# How to solve this IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

i`m with this IndexError: list index out of range error and don`t know how to solve it, i have to create and sort a random list 5,10,100,1000,10000. if i run this code once i don`t get this error

```
 import random
def bucketSort(array):
    bucket = []

    # Create empty buckets
    for i in range(len(array)):
        bucket.append([])

    # Insert elements into their respective buckets
    for j in array:
        index_b = j #int(10 * j)
        bucket[index_b].append(j)

    # Sort the elements of each bucket
    for i in range(len(array)):
        bucket[i] = sorted(bucket[i])

    # Get the sorted elements
    k = 0
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for j in range(len(bucket[i])):
            array[k] = bucket[i][j]
            k += 1
    return array
for i in range(10):
    nElementos = 10
    array = [0] * nElementos
    for i in range(nElementos):
        array[i] = random.randint(0,nElementos)
    print(array) 
    print("Sorted Array in descending order is")
    print(bucketSort(array))
```

> line 14, in bucketSort
> bucket[index_b].append(j) IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: just a guess, but what about for "line 14": `bucket[index_b-1].append(j)` ?

Answer (score 0):

If an item inside `array` is greater or equal to `len(array)` you will get an index error, since (in line 14) you are trying to insert that element into bucket, which has the same length of `array`.

The problem is this:

```
random.randint(0,nElementos)
```

This generates ints ranging from 0 to `nElementos`, **inclusive**. If a random number that is generated is the same as `nElementos`, the code will break, because it will basically try to do this:

```py
bucket[len(array)]
```

Assuming the rest of the code is correct, just change the random generation to this and it should work

```py
random.randint(0, nElementos - 1)
```